# PHP + Connect to Amazon ElastiCache

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

I'm using the following code to connect to Elasticache and have installed php-memcached and added /etc/php.d/memcached.ini - the connect doesn't error and seems to work:

```
  $server_endpoint = "etc-etc-etc.expalp.cfg.apse1.cache.amazonaws.com";
  $server_port = 11211;
  $dynamic_client = new Memcached();
  $dynamic_client->setOption(Memcached::OPT_CLIENT_MODE, Memcached::DYNAMIC_CLIENT_MODE);
  $dynamic_client->addServer($server_endpoint, $server_port);
  $dynamic_client->set('key', 'value', 60);
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How do I know if Consistant Hashing is enabled - I've read about its importance but don't know how to enable it or check its enabled.
2. Is there a way a can see what is written to Elasticache? I'm new to this and I would like to be able to confirm data is being written to the cache.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Its handled by an ini setting [More in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.configuration.php#ini.memcached.sess-consistent-hash)
2. I suppose the best way is to use the memcached client tools. Or just do a test, do you get back what you write?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<?php

$server_endpoint = "xxx.xx.xfg.sae1.cache.amazonaws.com";
$server_port = 11211;

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0') < 0) {
    //PHP 5.3 with php-pecl-memcache
    $client = new Memcache;
    $client->connect($server_endpoint, $server_port);
    //If you need debug see $client->getExtendedStats();
    $client->set('myKey', 'My Value PHP 5.3');
} else {
    //PHP 5.4 with php54-pecl-memcached:
    $client = new Memcached;
    $client->addServer($server_endpoint, $server_port);
    $client->set('myKey', 'My Value PHP 5.4');
}

echo 'Data in the cluster: [' . $client->get('myKey') . ']';
```